# Remove tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have tried various versions of "unwrap" but I keep getting unwrap is not a function. How do I ditch the b tags here?

```
<div id="top_left">
    <font size="3">
       <b>test</b>
    </font>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
jQuery("#top_left b").unwrap();
```

Comment: you can just use css to style the bold tag to unbold :)

Comment: With `unwrap()`. You need to show what you have tried for people to be able to say what's wrong with it. (Other than using `<font>`.)

Comment: And while you're at it, also remove the `<font>` tags. Please.

Comment: @Huangism it has a child - the text node. Try this `$("div font b").contents().unwrap()`

Comment: @Huangism It has a child TextNode. The linked duplicate works for it.

Comment: And while you're at it, change that `<b>` tag into a `<strong>` tag.

Comment: There is a function called .replaceWith in jQuery, so you can change a tag to something else, but as other has pointed out, the html should look more like this: <div id="top_left" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold">test</div> (or you can put the styles in a class, then you <div class='foo'>test</div>

Comment: oh then he can just unwrap it with the content

Comment: @h2ooooooo `strong` has semantic value. I wouldn't give semantic value to arbitrary markup which OP has no control over which seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way of doing this without `.unwrap()` is:

```
$('#top_left font').html($('#top_left font').text());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MJpXU/)**

And as some of the commenters pointed out, `<font>` was deprecated a looong time ago.

Comment: Two queries to unwrap a string ? :/

Comment: @Virus721 - queries? you mean selectors? and yes, but so what?

Comment: So queries are probably the slowest thing you can do with the dom, especially when you're not using the native querySelector method. Storing the result of the first query in a variable to reuse it when needed seems the minimum required imo.

Comment: @Virus721 - if you're going to be doing a high volume of them, then sure, performance might drop, however in this case I don't see that as being a problem.

Comment: Well if you have to change the content of the query string, you have to do it twice. Wasting performance is acceptable, but only when it helps make your code easier to read and debug, and when it helps you making less errors. In that case it not only doesn't help but also makes maintainability worse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that "test" isn't an element but a text node.

Assuming your real HTML could be more complex, that is there could be many `b` elements, and some text not in `b` elements, you should do something like this

```
$('#top_left b').replaceWith(function(){
  return $('<span>', {text:$(this).text()});
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/etuhif/1/edit) (click "Run with JS")

But usually, you would handle this kind of situation by starting with a `span` having a class giving it a `font-weight:bold` and just changing its class. `b`, `i`, `font`, and similar elements are rarely useful today and they make all style changes much heavier.

Answer (score 0):

```
var b = document.getElement... // Get your b tag
b.outerHTML = b.innerHTML;
```

This could maybe work without having to use jQuery. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Im not sure outerHTML is really cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to `unwrap` html tag but its content

You can use following  for this

```
$('#top_left b').contents().unwrap();
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/dHxKW/13/)